# Ask some search engine to what is this image?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, search, yahoo-api, bing

I want to develop some mobile app. Users can put or take their item photos and my app will say this is something.

for example; When I take pictures of my chair and ask it, my app should say this is chair.

I want to query with images and I want to get my results with keyword.

Are there any API to do this ? or What should I use to build this app ?

Any recommendation appreciated.

Have a nice coding !

Comment: look at google cloud vision api

Comment: Thank you. Vision API is ok for me

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is neural networks. Try researching the google neural networks and see if that is something you're interested in exploring.

Warning, it may be a rabbit hole. :)

Some starter links:

[Analysis of Neural Networks](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html)

[Google's TensorFlow](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.52839&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false)

Comment: answer is too generic